# Collecting Multiple Properties Of An Object To An Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, properties

Imagine I have an `example` object with the properties: `alpha`, `beta`, `charlie`, `delta`, `echo`, `foxtrot`, `gamma`, `hotel`.

I want to collect the values of some of these properties into an array.

I could do:

```
properties = [example.beta, example.delta, example.gamma, example.hotel]
```

**But is there a way to avoid repeating the object?**

If it was a single property I could do:

```
properties = example.map(&:beta)
```

So I'm looking for an equivalent to this (which doesn't work):

```
properties = example.map(&:beta, &:delta, &:gamma, &:hotel)
```

Comment: Is your example object a hash?

Comment: @asiniy Nope. It's a class instance.

Comment: Please try `example.attributes`. Does it return a hash with `alpha`, `beta` and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
properties = [:alpha, :beta, :charlie, :delta, :echo].map { |sym| example.send sym }
```

**UPDATE**

Accoridng to Jörg W Mittag's comment, it is also possible to:

```
properties = [:alpha, :beta, :charlie, :delta, :echo].map(&example.method(:send))
```

Comment: @JörgWMittag, Thank you for the comment. I will update the answer to include it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag :D do you really think that another coder will understand what it is? It's a cool as a shortcut, but not good at regular coding.

Comment: @asiniy: The unary prefix ampersand `&` operator for converting an object into a block is pretty widely known, I would think. You see it all over the place. And point-free style is widely used in Haskell and other languages.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the interface you want :

```
properties = example.map(:beta, :delta, :gamma, :hotel)
```

then I think this would do :

```
module AttrCollector
  def attr_values(*attr_names)
    attr_names.map do |attr_name|
      respond_to?(attr_name) ? send(attr_name) : nil
    end
  end
end

class Example
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
  include AttrCollector

  def initialize
    @a,@b,@c = 1,2,3
  end
end

example = Example.new
p example.attr_values(:a, :b, :c)
# => [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of @falsetru's answer.

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :alpha, :beta, :gamma

  def initialize(alpha, beta, gamma)
    self.alpha, self.beta, self.gamma = alpha, beta, gamma
  end

  def properties(*attributes)
    attributes.map { |a| send a }
  end
end

example = Example.new('dog', 'cat', 'pig')
example.properties(:alpha, :gamma)
  #=> ["dog", "pig"]
```

If you change `send a` to `send a.to_sym` you could invoke `properties` with symbols or strings:

```
example.properties('alpha', 'gamma')
  #=> ["dog", "pig"]
```